# lightdm black screen after installing plasma5 in Ubuntu

Tags: unity, lightdm, plasma-5

I have both ubuntu-desktop and kubuntu-destop installed on my laptop. While sddm works perfectly fine during login, if I choose lightdm as the default login screen, after a reboot, I get a black screen. 
The black screen goes away if I remove Kubuntu completely and only gnome files are present.

How do I fix this black screen issue?

OS: Ubuntu 15.04 x64 with Unity 7 and Plasma 5

Comment: Could you try my answer here https://askubuntu.com/q/697529/26246

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue, just removing sddm was enough to get lightdm working again

```
apt-get remove --purge sddm
```

searching for the problem brought up some issues regarding the coexistence of lightdm and sddm -> since you'll almost always only need one login-manager anyway, removing sddm should be OK to solve this problem