# LightDM & SDDM fight on greeter screen

Tags: upgrade, lightdm, login-screen, systemd, sddm

I had installed Kubuntu 15.04 sometime ago. I upgraded to 15.10, things were going fine till I added `ubuntu-desktop` to use Unity DE.

When booting with systemd, on startup or login, I get black or white screen for all Virtual Terminamls (TV's / TTY's) including TV7 graphical one. In some rare cases flickering screen between lightdm & sddm GUI, and that's how I got to know that both were running and may be the cause of this problem (black screen).

It works fine: when booting with upstart or switching DM back to sddm.

- Flickering screen between KDE/sddm Unity/lightdm

  https://youtu.be/xI1fpTyklNo 
  https://youtu.be/HpH309GqFcU
- `ps ax | grep dm`

  ```
   1377 ?        SLsl   0:00 /usr/sbin/lightdm
   1459 tty7     Ssl+   1:10 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
   1526 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/sddm
   1626 ?        SLl    0:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
   3843 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto dm
  ```
- `systemctl status default.target`

  ```
  ● graphical.target - Graphical Interface
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active since Fri 2015-11-13 09:46:21 CET; 50min ago
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

  Nov 13 09:46:21 BlueSkies systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
  ```
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

  ```
  Default display manager:
      gdm
    * lightdm
      sddm
      xdm
  ```
- `ls -l /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service`

  ```
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Nov 13 17:26 /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service -> /lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service
  ```

I don't want to remove any DM, also I do want to keep LightDM as default. So, is there a canonical answer to How to set the default DM for this mixed release 15.10 (systemd/upstart)?

I could find many similar question without the answer I'm looking for:

- [lightdm black screen after installing plasma5 in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/624339/26246)
- [lightdm doesn't show up](https://askubuntu.com/q/643322/26246)
- [kubuntu 15.04 upgrade: many problems](https://askubuntu.com/q/614663/26246)
- [No login screen on startup, works after logging in and logging out again](https://askubuntu.com/q/659347/26246)
- [Dual boot ubunuty/windows 10 partition on Dell xps 13](https://askubuntu.com/a/668085/26246), see Palantir's answer:

  > I found the kubuntu installer would not handle full disk encryption
  >   correctly, so I installed with Ubuntu installer, and added the
  >   kubuntu-desktop package later. I had serious problems with LightDM (it
  >   would appear and immediately disappear after boot, also it would not
  >   allow me to switch VTs), so I switched to KDE's sddm and its login
  >   manager (hint: sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm).

Comment: Hi, my answer is not relevant to this question. The problem was caused by the i810 drivers not being correctly loaded into the initrd. This has been solved in 15.10 (kernels in the 4.x series). Your problem on the other hand is not relevant to drivers issues (in my opinion) but to multiple login managers beind started.

Comment: @Palantir Yep, definitely your answer is not related but that behavior with lightdm is the same. Could you check the you still have blank screen on login (with no VT too) when using lightdm (instead of sddm)?

Comment: We've been using full disk encryption on Kubuntu install at work ever since it came out years ago. No issues...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I end up adding a `ExecStartPre` line to check for default display manager on legacy settings `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`, now it's working well:

`/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple Desktop Display Manager
Documentation=man:sddm(1) man:sddm.conf(5)
After=systemd-user-sessions.service getty@tty1.service plymouth-quit.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '[ "$(basename $(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null))" = "sddm" ]'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sddm
Restart=always
#PrivateTmp=yes

[Install]
Alias=display-manager.service
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

**Reference:** Copied from `/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service`

I'm not familiar with `systemd`, so no idea why `sddm` was started on boot. I have `gdm` too, it does not start by itself.

**Update:** I Could find a related bug report

- [Launchpad Bug-report #1446760: SDDM and LightDM can run at the same time](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sddm/+bug/1446760)

Comment: Just reported this upstream, referenced now in LP-bug.