# Screen Goes Blank After Boot

Tags: kde, intel-graphics, login-screen

Once I start my computer Ubuntu starts to boot by showing the splash screen. Then once the splash screen goes away the login screen appears, but then quickly goes blank.

I uploaded a YouTube video showing exactly what's going on: https://youtu.be/WUogY4_Zf-E

This started happening after I rebooted my computer after I installed kde-desktop.

Comment: Seems same as my question here   https://askubuntu.com/questions/697529/lightdm-sddm-fight-on-greeter-screen Could you try the accepted answer there or if there any other solution on the bug report linked there too.

Comment: What type of system is this? Is it a laptop/desktop, and especially important is what graphics card you have. Can you run the command `lspci | grep VGA`? It spits out details about your graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a while back.  It would get to the login screen, and I could type in a username/password, but at some point it would go blank, and restart X.

It eventually went away when I upgraded to a different video driver, and inspite looking for it, I couldn't find anyone else talking about the same symptoms.

I suggest you try a few things, which you may already have done.  Firstly try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F9 to see if you can terminate X and get back to the text screen.  Secondly try ssh-ing into the machine when it's gone black, see if it's still running, or if it has kernel dumped.

In my case it would come back, after a restart, but it was pretty much guaranteed to die when it was first started, then as I said, it started working perfectly, before ultimately, my GPU died.  My laptop is an XPS, and apparently its a common problem that they run hot, over time, and the GPU comes unsoldered.  The blank screens could a sign of something crashing intermittently.